# Red Hat Dev studio is not responding when ActiveMQ-Blueprint DSL template as new project is selected

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi, jboss-developer-studio

[Red Hat Deve Studio Not Respnding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL3Fr.jpg)Red Hat Developer Studio 12.0.0.GA (2) stops responding whenever ActiveMQ-Blueprint DSL template for new camel integration project is selected.
Have disable auto build, suspended validators, restarted the machine, yet the problem persists.
As such, whenever OSGI blueprint file is selected, the IDE takes too long to respond, and if we kill the IDE process for its sluggish response, Studio doesn't get relaunched as it hangs while loading UI plugin.
Bit of a roadblock while getting things started up.
Any resolution on how to get the IDE to stop from going into not responding mode while using importing blueprint project templates and while using them.

Answer (score 3):

if you create a new Fuse integration project from the template for the first time, it takes a long time because of all required dependencies have to be downloaded. This task could take several minutes depends on your internet connection speed. It should end eventually. Try to be more patient.

I'm able to create a new Fuse integration project from ActiveMQ - Blueprint DSL example.